# Using yield inside define_method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Is it possible to make **yield** keyword work inside a block given to define_method? Simple example:

```
class Test
  define_method :test do |&b|
    puts b    # => #<Proc:...>
    yield
  end
end

Test.new.test {
  puts "Hi!"
}
```

This code produces following error in both Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.0:

> test.rb:4:in `test': no block given (LocalJumpError)
>       from test.rb:8

The strange thing is the **b** block variable `!= nil` but `block_given?` returns false. Is it intentional Ruby behaviour not to recognize blocks by **Proc** objects?

**Edit:** Regards to **Beerlington**'s answer: `b.call()` is is not what I am looking for. Block variable was used only to indicate that block is actually given, and is not detected inside define_method.

### Reason why I need use `yield` instead of `block.call`

I am willing to write some extension to the way how new classes are defined in Ruby, thus *any* code You can write in pure Ruby should be accepted when I use my extension.

So similar semantics cannot be taken into consideration, because this forces users of my library to use only one proper way to pass a block. This breaks the TIMTOWTDI rule, and does not make my library transparent.

### Real life example

Code below can be simplified to code above since `my_def` uses `define_method`:

```
require 'my_library'

class Test
  # client can write 'my_def' instead of 'def' since
  # my_library extends Class class
  my_def :test, "some parameter" do
    yield        # oh no, error :(
  end
end

Test.new.test {
  puts "Hi!"
}
```

Comment: Not answering, but related: you can't test `block_given`  either inside `define_method`. Test for the block, like here: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3486000

Answer (score 29):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
class Test
  define_method :test do |&b|
    b.call
  end
end

Test.new.test {
  puts "Hi!"
}
```

More at http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2008/10/29/using-define_method-with-blocks-in-ruby-18/

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I am looking for. I know I can call block this way, but I need to use yield. b variable was used only to indicate that block is actually given.

Comment: @Dejw, This *is* the droid you're looking for.  Taking &block as an argument and invoking block.call on it has the same semantics as calling "yield."  Beerlington's code works in both 1.8.7 and 1.9.

Comment: @Wayne: You may think this is the solution but is not. I did not write the purpose of using `yield` instead of `block.call` and the reason _why_ is in my question now.

Comment: @Dejw, Thanks for the added explanation.  I have to admit that I'm still confused: block.call not only has the same semantics as yield, it has the exact same syntax for the caller (see Beerlington's code: He's not passing the block in as an argument).  The caller can't tell which one the method is using.  What am I missing?

Comment: The problem is that _the caller_ may write `yield` instead of `block.call`. The code I have given is possible caller's code. Extended method definition in my library can be simplified to my code above. Client provides block passed to define_method (body of a method), so he/she can write there anything. Especially `yield`. I can write in documentation that `yield` simply does not work, but I am trying to avoid that, and make my library 100% compatible with Ruby (alow to use any language syntax, not only a subset).

Comment: @Dejw, Thanks again for your patience in explaining this.

Answer (score 23):

You cannot use `yield` inside a `define_method` block. This is because blocks are captured by closures, observe:

```
def hello
  define_singleton_method(:bye) { yield }
end

hello { puts "hello!" }

bye {  puts "bye!" } #=> "hello!"
```

I don't think your users will mind not being able to use 'yield' in the way you state ---- the syntax is *nothing* like ordinary Ruby method definition syntax so there is unlikely to be any confusion.

More information on why you cannot pass blocks implicitly to methods found here: http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2010/11/06/behavior-of-yield-in-define_method/

Comment: Wow, thanks for the explanation, I was wondering why doesn't it work. This should be the accepted answer