# Implicit block passing and dynamically defined methods

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, proc

Please consider the following different ways to define method `m`:

- Method 1:

  ```
  class C
    def m; yield; end
  end
  ```
- Method 2:

  ```
  class C
    def initialize
      (class << self; self; end).class_eval do            
        define_method(:m){|&b| b.call }
      end
    end
  end
  ```
- Method 3:

  ```
  class C
    def initialize
      (class << self; self; end).class_eval do            
        define_method(:m){puts block_given?; yield}            
      end
    end
  end
  ```

Then I can invoke `m` using `Object#send`.

```
o = C.new
o.send(:m) {puts 'test'}
```

While calling `m` using Method 1 or Method 2 works fine, Method 3 gives this error:

```
no block given (yield) (LocalJumpError)
```

I understand that a block is not an object, but instead just a part of method calling syntax and you cannot pass an implicit block from one function to another without writing something obscure like this:

```
def printer
  yield
end
def proxy
  printer &Proc.new
end

proxy { puts "&Proc.new probably creates Proc object from block"}
```

But in that case, why does Method 1 work? It would be awesome to get an answer which would explain what's happening under the hood.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "define ... statically", "with an explicit block", or "the first case". I can guess you are probably mentioning either your Method 1, Method 2, or Method 3, but it is not clear which.

Comment: @sawa I thought it would be clear with the code fragment. You quotted Method 1, Method 2 and Method 1 respectively:)

Comment: Why did you use `send` to call `m`? It doesn't look like it has any meaning.

Comment: @sawa this code is derived from a context where it should be called like that, but in this particular case it doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: In case you are not aware, in Method 2 you could call `class_eval` on the class, rather than on the singleton class: `self.class.class_eval do`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with Method 3 is the scope. `yield` refers to the block passed to `initialize`, if any. It does not refer to the block passed to `m`. And since you created `o` by `C.new` without a block, the expected `yield` is absent, and that causes the error.

In Method 1, `yield` refers to the block passed to `m`. In Method 2, `b` refers to a proc converted from the block passed to `m`.

Comment: Ah, I see! But is it possible to use `yield` in a dynamically defined method?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306731/using-yield-inside-define-method-in-ruby).